# Approximation for spin operator anticommutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, linear-algebra

I would like to understand better the derivation of an identity I saw on a presentation.
Consider the standard spin-$J$ operators $\hat{J}_X$, $\hat{J}_Y$, $\hat{J}_Z$, for a state fully polarised along the $Z$ direction we have
\begin{equation}\label{eq}
\hat{J}_Z \hat{J}_Y + \hat{J}_Y \hat{J}_Z \approx (2J-1)\hat{J}_Y \;. \tag{1}
\end{equation}

How can this be derived rigorously?

**EDIT 1:** note that the above approximate equality has to be understood in the expectation-value sense, for states highly polarised along $Z$. Namely, $\langle \hat{J}_Z \hat{J}_Y + \hat{J}_Y \hat{J}_Z \rangle \approx (2J-1)  \langle \hat{J}_Y  \rangle$, where $\langle\cdot\rangle$ is the expectation value taken for a $Z$-polarized state.

**EDIT 2:** I tried numerically, and indeed the upper-right $2x2$ blocks of Eq.\eqref{eq} LHS and RHS indeed match, which is what I require (as the approximation is valid only for states highly polarised along $z$).

**EDIT 3:** Note that the above approximation is extremely useful for approximating Hamiltonians containing two-spin interactions terms under certain conditions.

Comment: For J=1/2, it is exact; have you looked at J=1 and a [higher spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(particle_physics)#Higher_spins)?

Comment: I checked numerically, and indeed the upper-left 2x2 block of the matrix representation matches. I'm wondering how to see it algebraically...

Comment: My question deals with arbitrary spin $J$. For $J=1/2$ my question is trivially answered. In my previous comment I meant that I checked numerically that the approximation I wrote holds for arbitrary spins (I tried up to $J=20$).

Answer (score 0):

> I checked numerically, and indeed the upper-left 2x2 block of the matrix representation matches. I'm wondering how to see it algebraically...

This much narrower question has a straightforward answer. I use the [WP conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(particle_physics)#Higher_spins) instead of yours, absorbing ℏ in the units,
$$
  \left(S_y\right)_{ab}  = \frac{i }{2} \left(\delta_{a,b+1} - \delta_{a+1,b}\right) \sqrt{(s + 1)(a + b - 1) - ab}, \\
  \left(S_z\right)_{ab}  =   (s + 1 - a) \delta_{a,b} = \hbar (s + 1 - b) \delta_{a,b},
$$
where the indices *a, b*  are integers   such that
$1 \le a \le 2s + 1, \quad 1 \le b \le 2s + 1$.

It then follows directly that the sparse antisymmetric "remainder" matrix
$$
R(s)_{ab}\equiv (S_zS_y+S_yS_z)_{ab} +(1-2s)(S_y)_{ab}\\ = \frac{i}{2} \sqrt{(s+1)(a+b-1) -ab}~(3-a-b)\left(\delta_{a,b+1} - \delta_{a+1,b}\right),  
$$
with the evident property you observed. The vanishing of the upper 2x2 block is an identity: you may try it at *s* = 137.

You may also observe that, e.g., the (3,2) entry, *a*=3, *b*=2, does not vanish as $s\to \infty$, growing as its square root, so it actually diverges, whatever the approximation scheme of your undisclosed reference is purported to be...

- Trivially, the dot product $\vec v\cdot A \vec v$ for any antisymmetric matrix such as *R* vanishes, strictly, and without approximation! But this is silly, since the sheer anticommutator given is such, and you need no $\approx$ nonsense. Your edit patched nothing.

Comment: The approximation is valid only for states highly polarised along $z$, so the 2x2 upper-left block being zero is enough. I know other matrix elements might diverge... I'm just wondering if it is possible to derive that approximation using spin-algebra identities. For example writing $S_y$ as $S_{\pm}$, etc. I tried, but so far I have not succeeded.

Comment: For the highest *m=J* there is no approximation involved, so you are mis-framing the issue! The explicit form I provide ***is*** the encoding of spin algebra identities. Did you perform the trivial matrix anticommutator involved? It is very unclear what you are wishing for. The explicit general answer is staring you in the face!